# After updating Android Studio Canary beta 1. I get the error min sdk 26

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My Gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tester.us_site"
    minSdkVersion 17
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

After compilation, I get this error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24
Information:BUILD FAILED in 40s
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

As I understand, this error says that in order to run the project it is necessary to specify min sdk 26.

But what about Android 5.0 6.0 7.0?

```
## Gradle Build ##
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Update your class path in gradle.build in project level.

Comment: @AslamHossin, Can be more. And then I did not understand something

Comment: just remove both 'build' folder in /android and /android/app
and build again with 'react-native run-android'

Comment: I did as you said, after the synchronization was done and still this error appeared

Comment: Last thing you can try by editing like this : 
compile group: 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins', name: 'android-apt', version: '1.8'


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149648/cannot-get-android-apt-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Change Guava 21 on 22.
and add 
force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'

This is working. All thx))

Comment: For me it was the use of Jackson-datatype-jsr310. I finally gave up on trying to use the java.time api in android. I guess its time to bring joda back to my project. As soon as I commented this line -> compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.0' my project started compiling using compileSdkVersion 26 and Android studio 3.0 beta2.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to upgrade it to the latest android-specific build

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0-android'
```

This fixed the error for me